# Blocking a network call from an SDK Android App

Tags: java, android, sdk, admob

I am using googles AdMob SDK and there is some kind of an initialization that happens during launch of the App which basically results in a dummy call( dummy response from google). Just to intialize and improve  performance of the Ads in our App google suggested this path. To be exact this is what they suggested to incorporate in the App.

```
PublisherAdView mAdView = new PublisherAdView (this);
mAdView.setAdUnitId( this.getResources().getString(R.string. banner_ad_unit_id));
mAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize. BANNER, AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE);
PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Now after doing this its making a dummy ad call before the real Ad call is made and giving us improved performance for the real Ad call.

Problem: This now results in extra network calls and google said they will actually charge us for that, which is an added burden for us.

Now to get around this we tested a scenario where we black listed this dummy Ad call sent by the AdMob SDK and we still got improved performance. And this was done through a proxy and we specifically blocked this Ad call Url.

Now my question is there a way to get around this problem? I am looking for a way to basically drop the connection after making the call. SDK makes the request but it never reaches google servers inside our Android APP.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:-

The problem can be that you were using a mixed Java/XML approach for the same things. you must deleted all the Java and went purely XML and it will works fine.

Solution 2:-

Check the logcat output when testing on your device. It can be possible because of network connectivity issue and Also note that setTesting only requests test ads (the dummy Google ad) on an emulator, and is also deprecated for addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR) or
addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID_FOUND_IN_LOGCAT_WHEN_MAKING_A_REQUEST_ON_A‌​_DEVICE").
I hope it will help you .

Comment: my question is about getting a network call blocked after the AdMobs SDK makes it.  In the real world scenario I want the Admob SDK to make the Ad call and I want to implement a functionality which will basically block this call or rewrite this call.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on JAVA/XML approach? I am confused.

Comment: there are person who declare for their programming in both java and xml file

Comment: And where do you see I am using both JAVA and XML?

Comment: this is strange how come this answer is getting so many likes ... this answer is no where close to what I am asking

Comment: @ shubham sharma I am 1000% sure that you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Anyways I just flagged for moderation.